# Android project cloned, but Google Maps doesn't work on new computer

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api, maps

I have an Android app project that uses the Google Maps API. I needed to clone it to another computer, but it doesn't seem to work on the new computer.

The error messages reads as follows:
E/Google Maps Android API﹕ Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start for how to correctly set up the map.
E/Google Maps Android API﹕ In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
    Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
    Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
    API Key: *MY API KEY*(which works on the old computer)

I have tried generating a new API key and using this, same result.
I have tried enabling all Google services in the SDK manager, same result.

Any advice?

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<!--
```

The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
    -->

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ExamineRoom"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_examine_room" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".checkAvailable"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_check_available" >
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Can you post the code of your manifest file? Also, make sure `Google Maps Android API v2` is enabled in your Google Developer Console.

Comment: Ok, I added it. Yes, the Google Maps Android API v2 is enabled.

Comment: What do you mean by not work? Does it show gray window? That means your API key setting not correct. Try to use `Server key` instead of `Android key` to see if it works.

Comment: I assume that you changed your computer, so you need to generate another `Android key`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are using the default keystore. So when you clone your project to another PC. The default keystore on the new PC is different from previous one. What you have to do is generate a new API key. [Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/signup) you can find detailed tutorial.

1. Get the default debug certificate fingerprint. Before this you should know where is your default keystore located.

   OS X and Linux: ~/.android/
   Windows Vista and Windows 7: C:\Users\your_user_name.android\

For mac please use command:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

For windows use this:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "%USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

And the output should be something like this:

```
Alias name: androiddebugkey
Creation date: Jan 01, 2013
Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=Android Debug, O=Android, C=US
Issuer: CN=Android Debug, O=Android, C=US
Serial number: 4aa9b300
Valid from: Mon Jan 01 08:04:04 UTC 2013 until: Mon Jan 01 18:04:04 PST 2033
Certificate fingerprints:
     MD5:  AE:9F:95:D0:A6:86:89:BC:A8:70:BA:34:FF:6A:AC:F9
     SHA1: BB:0D:AC:74:D3:21:E1:43:07:71:9B:62:90:AF:A1:66:6E:44:5D:75
     Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA
     Version: 3
```

Now you got the SHA1: **BB:0D:AC:74:D3:21:E1:43:07:71:9B:62:90:AF:A1:66:6E:44:5D:75**

2. Get a new API key for this new SHA1 (You have gone through this before)

Go to your Google Developer Console. Generate the new API key with is SHA1 code and your package name. For example:

```
BB:0D:AC:74:D3:21:E1:43:67:71:9B:62:91:AF:A1:66:6E:44:5D:75;com.example.android.mapexample
```

Now you get your new API key. Update it in your AndroidManifest.xml and put it into the meta-data:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="API_KEY"/>
```

After all these, you map will just show as it did. Hope this post helps you. Cheers.

Comment: What is the recommended approach: Copy debug.keystore from another pc or generate new sha1 fingerprint on different computers and add in google console account?

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to not generate a new key and instead add a new restriction to the existing key, enter the same project name 'com.example.fruit.cucumber' in the restrictions, and pull your new SHA1 (from your new device). Then press save and go rebuild and run your project on your new PC.